# ng2-chart is only refreshing when cursor is in a certain position

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-charts

I have a page in my angular2 web app where I'm displaying a list of items. Next to this is a sidebar menu.
 
When one of the items in the list is selected, I'm showing an additional detail view that includes a radar chart (using [the ng2-charts library](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts)) that binds to an array of data. Since I'm fetching the data I want to display from a database, the array is initialized using some default data and later updated using an observable:

```
public spiderChartData:any = [
    {label: "",fill:false, scaleShowLabels : false, borderWidth:5, 
    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
   data: [30,30,30,30,30]}
];
constructor(private fs : FirebaseService) { }
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.fs.getWorkoutRatings(this.wName).valueChanges().subscribe(res => {
        this.ratings = res.map(x=>x);
        console.log("data received");
        this.spiderChartData = [
            {label: "",fill:false, scaleShowLabels : false, borderWidth:5, 
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            data: this.ratings;
    });
```

}

I can see from the log that the required data is received almost instantly. However, for some reason, the chart doesn't not redraw until I move the cursor over the sidebar menu; then the chart is updated instantly.
**I would like the chart to get updated as soon as new data is received.** 
 I have tried updating the chart manually or even destroying and redrawing it, but nothing so far has fixed this issue.

---

### additional info

relevant html:

```
<canvas baseChart
    [datasets]="spiderChartData"
    [labels]="spiderChartLabels"
    [chartType]="spiderChartType"
    [options]="spiderChartOptions"
    [colors]="spiderChartColours"
    (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
    (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
</canvas>
```

- I have pretty much copied all of the code for the chart from another, much simpler, project of mine which was basically just one page showing this chart. There the automatic update worked without any problems.
- I'm having trouble isolating a minimal working example for demonstration, but I' hoping someone will be able to help me anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because your `spiderChartData` array remains the same as per Angular Change Detection. What I mean is the reference doesn't change only the `data` property inside.

`Angular` unlike `AngularJS` doesn't dirty check for value change; it compares variables using `===` instead of `==`.

So for Angular to run Change Detection, use :

```
    public spiderChartData:any = []; //<--- initialize as empty array to begin with

    constructor(private fs : FirebaseService) { }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.fs.getWorkoutRatings(this.wName).valueChanges().subscribe(res => {
            this.ratings = res.map(x=>x);
            console.log("data received");
            this.spiderChartData = [
                {label: "",fill:false, scaleShowLabels : false, borderWidth:5, 
                fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                data: this.ratings;
        });
   }
```

OR

If you want not to initialize array as empty then you need to call `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChange()`  in `ngAfterViewInit` so explicitly tell Angular to run change detection cycle.

```
public spiderChartData:any = [
    {label: "",fill:false, scaleShowLabels : false, borderWidth:5, 
    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
   data: [30,30,30,30,30]}
];

 constructor(private fs : FirebaseService
      private _cdRef : ChangeDetectorRef//<--- inject ChangeDetectorRef
      ) { }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.fs.getWorkoutRatings(this.wName).valueChanges().subscribe(res => {
            this.ratings = res.map(x=>x);
            console.log("data received");
            this.spiderChartData = [
                {label: "",fill:false, scaleShowLabels : false, borderWidth:5, 
                fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                data: this.ratings;
        });
    this._cdRef.detectChanges(); // <-- tell angular to run cd for this components and it's siblings
       }
```

Comment: Thanks, mate. This works for me. I changed `ChangeDetectionRef` in the second solution to `ChangeDetectorRef`; I suspect this was just a typo.

Comment: @deadpool your welcome. I have corrected the typo as well :)